# pi4j opposite state in java, normal in python

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pi4j

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and switches (jqc3f-05vdc-c).
When I run simple program on python like this:

```
[...]
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18, 0)
[...]
```

my sweatch is off, on when i set GPIO.output(18, 1), but when I run program in Java:

```
[...]
private GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
GpioPinDigitalMultipurpose gpio1 = gpio.provisionDigitalMultipurposePin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01,PinMode.DIGITAL_OUTPUT)
gpio1.low() //high state
gpio1.high() //low state
[...]
```

Default i have High state on all switches, but when i run method .high() my switch turn off.

Someone had the same problem?

Comment: what switch are you talking about? .... how is it connected to the RPi? .... how are you determining that the "switch" is on or off?

Comment: I am talking about Relay Module 5V x 8 Relay w/ Opto-isolation, it’s connected by: vcc to 5v, GND to GND, In1 to GPIO1 (PI4J schema). I am determining by dioda on the module and by electric meter.

Comment: Please add the information, you have given in the comment, to your question. You can edit it.